# Flexbox - how to prevent from expanding beyond it's container

Tags: html, css, flexbox, jsx

I'm pretty new to flexbox and I'm pulling my hair out over something very simple. Currently, I'm trying to create a container that has some elements and it shows up okay on my browser but when I try to resize the browser, everything starts expanding out of its container.

[image]
[image]

In the second photo, the text and images start to overflow and I'd like to keep it inside the white container.

```
return <div id="parent" className="Container2">
            <div className="container2_title">
              <div className="title">
                <p>Parking — A Problem Worth Solving</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="container2_content">
              <div className="row" style={{ textAlign: 'left' }}>
                <img src={timer} style={{ float: "left" }} />
                <p>
                  An average person in the U.S. spends about
                  <span className="purk-color">
                    17 hours per year
                  </span>
                  searching for parking. In metropolitan areas like Los Angeles, this number goes up to
                  <span className="purk-color">
                    85 hours per year
                  </span>.
                </p>
                <p>
                  Additionally, it takes
                  <span className="purk-color">
                    15–32 minutes per trip
                  </span>
                  to find a parking spot.
                </p>
              </div>
              <div className="row" style={{textAlign: 'right'}}>
                <img src={charging} style={{ float: "right" }} />
                <p>
                  <span className="purk-color">63% </span>
                  of Americans reported that they avoided driving to a destination due to parking.
                  </p>
                <p>
                  Parking accounts for
                    <span className="purk-color">
                    30% of traffic
                    </span>, produces
                    <span className="purk-color">
                    2.5M tons of harmful emissions
                    </span>, and wastes
                    <span className="purk-color">
                    260M gallons of gas
                    </span>.
                  </p>
              </div>
              <div className="row" style={{ textAlign: 'left' }}>
                <img src={moneybag} style={{ float: "left" }} />
                <p>
                  Overpaying for parking costs the U.S.
                  <span className="purk-color">
                    20B annually
                  </span>. In the top 10 busiest cities in America, this averages out to
                  <span className="purk-color">
                    $1205 per driver per year.
                  </span>
                </p>
                <p>
                  In cities like Los Angeles, it costs about
                  <span className="purk-color"> $200 per </span>
                  month for long term parking, and about
                  <span className="purk-color"> $14 for two-hour </span>
                  parking.
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>;
```

Here's my css:

```
.Container2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
  color: #fff;
  /* background-color: #ffa38b; */
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container2_title {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  align-self: center;

  font-size: 7vh;
  color: #777777;
}

.container2_content {
  color: #777777;
  padding-left: 10%;
  padding-right: 10%;
}

.container2_content .row {
  height: 15%;
}

.purk-color {
  color: #ffa38b;
}

.container2_content img {
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you! :-)

Comment: Have you tried using `max-height` or `min-height` instead of `height`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is a mockup](https://codepen.io/broderickdevelopment/pen/NLZVgV) of how you can rectify this issue using media queries. The basic principle is:

- The two containers combined take up the width of the view window.
- After the view window `width` goes below `600px`. The `width` of both containers changes so that they take up the `100%` of the view window

This is the most common way to display to implement responsive design for multiple sections of content on a single row when screensize gets too small.

```css
body {
 font-family: arial;
}

.container {
 width: 95%;
 max-width: 1024px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.sub-container {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 display: inline-block;
 border: 1px solid black;
 width: 49%;
 padding: 20px;
 margin-top: 10px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
   
    .sub-container {
     display: block;
     width: 100%;
    }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="sub-container">
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
   tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
   quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
   consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
   cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
   proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="sub-container">
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
   tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
   quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
   consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
   cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
   proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
 </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you have set the `Container2` height to a fixed value of `100vh`, it seems that it will not expand when the content takes up more room. You should try using `min-height: 100vh`. This way, the container will stay the size of the screen, but increase if it needs to. You could also try using `overflow-y: scroll` if you would like the container to scroll to fit in all content whilst keeping a fixed height.

Comment: is there a way I can do it without expanding my `Container2`? Instead of having it expands, can I have the contents shrink base on the `Container2` size?

Comment: you could use a [media query](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) to dynamically change the `font-size` attribute of the container based on the width of the view window. Or you could use them so that both containers become the full width of the screen and they arrange in columns if the view window gets too small.